# How to detect if Firefox uses "Do not remember history" setting?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have to disable my PWA when the Firefox browser is in such state because it does rely extensively on IndexedDb which does not work in that state.

How can I check for this setting being ON or OFF with JavaScript?